# Running 32-bit ASP.NEt 3.5 apps in Windows 2003 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, windows-server-2003, 32-bit

I've managed to get my 32-bit apps working on IIS in Windows Server 2003 64-bit, but I'm wondering if I will encounter any other issues doing so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One issue with IIS6 (but fixed in IIS7) is that you are stuck using either 32-bit or 64-bit ASP.NET worker processes.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx ...

However, if you really need to access 32-bit DLLs in your ASP.NET app, then 32-bit worker processes will do what you need.  Is that why you switched to 32-bit ASP.NET in the first place?  Such as described in http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/10/13/133121.aspx ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you're using AppPool isolation (hosting multiple clients), 32bit mode is recommended for smaller footprint. See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/291/general-iis7-questions/